# Extracting the coordinates and atom types from a pymatgen structure object

Tags: pymatgen

What is the syntax for extracting the atomic coordinates list, [[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ...] and atomic species list, eg. [1,1,1,1,...] from a pymatgen structure object?

Comment: Please reply, I am new to pymatgen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but in case you (or someone else) needs the answer, it goes as follows:

```py
from pymatgen.core.structure import Structure, Lattice

structure = Structure(lattice, atoms, coords)#some structure

coordinates = []
species = []

for s in structure:
        coordinates.append(s.coords) #cartesian coordinates
        #coordinates.append(s.frac_coords) #would give fractional coordinates instead
        species.append(s.specie.Z)
        #species.append(s.specie) #would give strings (e.g. "Fe") instead of atomic number

print(coordinates)
print(species)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Import Structure object from pymatgen

```
from pymatgen import Structure
```

## read the cif structure from .cif file

```
structure_from_cif = Structure.from_file('mp-773116La20S29O.cif')
```

## get the coordinates

```
cartesian_coords = structure_from_cif.cart_coords
```

## to get the species you can do the following

```
for i in structure_from_cif.species:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what the code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.